# How to install latest python version for SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2017 with Python but it came with Python 3.5.2 and Anaconda 4.2.0. Is there a way to upgrade the Python to 3.7?

This is the only official document I found and tried

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/use-sqlbindr-exe-to-upgrade-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 but even this installed 3.5

Please help.

Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: have you try using docker? That way both versions are independent of each other

Comment: @JoseAngelSanchez I am sorry but how is docker related to SQL Server? I am trying to run Python scripts from SQL Server (from SSMS).

Comment: Hoy can run SQL un Docker, it Is always a good option, but it Is just a sugestion

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to open https://www.python.org/downloads/ and install the latest release. If you have Visual Studio 2017/2019, open the solution explorer, open your python project (or import a new one into a Python Application) and point your application to this latest version. Either way, the latest version will exist on the machine. Note that some versions may be 32 bit and not 64 bit.
PyCharm Community Edition is another option.

Answer (score 0):

this may help. a brief scan of it looks like  there is a package created just for this purpose, dating python version and packages on SQL server machines:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/install-additional-python-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

I am using pyodbc with Python 3.7. I am running an older version of SQL-Server, but it should work on your version too.

So just install Python 3.7, import pyodbc, set the "driver" specifically to a SQL Server client and you are good to go.